# Is there any procedure to exclude taxonomy vocabulary terms from views display

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I am using **drupal7**. I created a view with nodes under **category(Taxonomy) Vehicle.**

It looks fine, I am able to output a good looking page with set of images, title,desc etc along with **tags(I mean vocabulary == Vehicle)..** Can any one guide me how to **exclude taxonomy name from displaying in view**.

Please help..

Thank you.

Comment: please clear your question. What do you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

you can use exclude display from view 
[image]

Comment: And if you just want to exclude the taxonomy label, uncheck "Create a label".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what you want to do, if you're excluding a whole set of tags, or just individual ones.

If you're excluding individual ones, you can add a filter for "Term Name" and choose "Is not" or "Does not contain" and put the text of the name you want to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

If you are listing full node in view then you can use 'view mode'. For D7, you can try this contrib module. https://www.drupal.org/project/ds